# Android PHP requests to MySQL

Tags: java, php, android, sql

I'm trying to use android to send http requests to my server. The server has PHP scripts on it to add/ delete/ edit items in the MySQL database. 
I can't tell if I'm even connecting to the server or what's happening when the code is executed, I get Error parsing data org.json.JSONException: Value

I'm very new to PHP and have been following this tutorial for guide lines, "http://www.androidhive.info/2012/05/how-to-connect-android-with-php-mysql/" but I'm pretty stuck.

PHP to add drink

```
<?php

/*
 * Following code will create a new product row
 * All product details are read from HTTP Post Request
 */

// array for JSON response
$response = array();

// check for required fields
if (isset($_POST['name']) && isset($_POST['price']) && isset($_POST['quantity'])) {

$name = $_POST['name'];
$price = $_POST['price'];
$quantity = $_POST['quantity'];

// include db connect class
require_once __DIR__ . '/db_connect.php';

// connecting to db
$db = new DB_CONNECT();

// mysql inserting a new row
$result = mysql_query("INSERT INTO drinks(name, price, quantity) VALUES('$name', '$price', '$quantity')");

// check if row inserted or not
if ($result) {
    // successfully inserted into database
    $response["success"] = 1;
    $response["message"] = "Product successfully created.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
} else {
    // failed to insert row
    $response["success"] = 0;
    $response["message"] = "Oops! An error occurred.";

    // echoing JSON response
    echo json_encode($response);
}
} else {
// required field is missing
$response["success"] = 0;
$response["message"] = "Required field(s) is missing";

// echoing JSON response
echo json_encode($response);
}?>
```

New drink activity:

```
public class NewDrinkActivity extends Activity {

// Progress Dialog
private ProgressDialog pDialog;

JSONParser jsonParser = new JSONParser();
EditText inputName;
EditText inputPrice;
EditText inputQuantity;

// url to create new Drink
private static String url_create_Drink =    "http://jjohnson.bugs3.com/android_connect/create_drink.php";

// JSON Node names
private static final String TAG_SUCCESS = "success";

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.add_drink);

    // Edit Text
    inputName = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtName);
    inputPrice = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtPrice);
    inputQuantity = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edtQuantity);

    // Create button
    Button btnAddDrink = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);

    // button click event
    btnAddDrink.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            // creating new Drink in background thread
            new CreateNewDrink().execute();
        }
    });
}

/**
 * Background Async Task to Create new Drink
 * */
class CreateNewDrink extends AsyncTask<String, String, String> {

    /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(NewDrinkActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Creating Drink..");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(true);
        pDialog.show();
    }

    /**
     * Creating Drink
     * */
    protected String doInBackground(String... args) {
        String name = inputName.getText().toString();
        String price = inputPrice.getText().toString();
        String quantity = inputQuantity.getText().toString();

        // Building Parameters
        List<NameValuePair> params = new ArrayList<NameValuePair>();
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("name", name));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("price", price));
        params.add(new BasicNameValuePair("quantity", quantity));

        // getting JSON Object
        // Note that create Drink url accepts POST method
        JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_Drink,
                "POST", params);

        // check log cat fro response
        Log.d("Create Response", json.toString());

        // check for success tag
        try {
            int success = json.getInt(TAG_SUCCESS);

            if (success == 1) {
                // successfully created Drink
                Intent i = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), StockActivity.class);
                startActivity(i);

                // closing this screen
                finish();
            } else {
                // failed to create Drink
            }
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return null;
    }

    /**
     * After completing background task Dismiss the progress dialog
     * **/
    protected void onPostExecute(String file_url) {
        // dismiss the dialog once done
        pDialog.dismiss();
    }

}
}
```

JSON Parser:

```
public class JSONParser {

static InputStream is = null;
static JSONObject jObj = null;
static String json = "";

// constructor
public JSONParser() {

}

// function get json from url
// by making HTTP POST or GET method
public JSONObject makeHttpRequest(String url, String method,
        List<NameValuePair> params) {

    // Making HTTP request
    try {

        // check for request method
        if(method == "POST"){
            // request method is POST
            // defaultHttpClient
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(params));

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();

        }else if(method == "GET"){
            // request method is GET
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            String paramString = URLEncodedUtils.format(params, "utf-8");
            url += "?" + paramString;
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(url);

            HttpResponse httpResponse = httpClient.execute(httpGet);
            HttpEntity httpEntity = httpResponse.getEntity();
            is = httpEntity.getContent();
        }           

    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    try {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(
                is, "iso-8859-1"), 8);
        StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
        String line = null;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
            sb.append(line + "\n");
        }
        is.close();
        json = sb.toString();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        Log.e("Buffer Error", "Error converting result " + e.toString());
    }

    // try parse the string to a JSON object
    try {
        jObj = new JSONObject(json);
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        Log.e("JSON Parser", "Error parsing data " + e.toString());
    }

    // return JSON String
    return jObj;

}
}
```

If it helps I'm using ServerFree.com to host my files.

Comment: for starters, http://jjohnson.bugs3.com/android_connect/create_product.php gives a 404. You are trying to acomplish a number of things simultaneously, and as you said you are new to php. First try to get the server side things working as expected. Get a firefox addon that creates POST requests, and test it until its working. Then, once you establish that the PHP script works, move on to android and enable http logging. This will show you the raw requests and responses so you know what is going on.

Comment: sorry meant android_connect/create_drink.php

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I think is happening...

You make the request, it is sent to the server, processed (PHP doesn't error out as I see) and you receive a response that looks like this:

> {"success":0,"message":"Required field(s) is missing"}

In reality, you're receiving the following from your webserver:

```
{"success":0,"message":"Required field(s) is missing"}<!-- www.serversfree.com Analytics Code -->
<script src="http://www.serversfree.com"></script><noscript><a title="Free hosting servers" href="http://www.serversfree.com">Free servers</a><a title="Free websites hosting server" href="http://www.serversfree.com">Free websites hosting server</a><a title="Free hosting server features" href="http://www.serversfree.com/server-features/">Free server features</a><a title="Free hosting" href="http://www.bugs3.com">Free hosting</a></noscript>
<script type="text/javascript">

  var _gaq = _gaq || [];
  _gaq.push(['_setAccount', 'UA-24425628-3']);
  _gaq.push(['_setDomainName', window.location.host]);
  _gaq.push(['_setAllowLinker', true]);
  _gaq.push(['_trackPageview']);

  (function() {
    var ga = document.createElement('script'); ga.type = 'text/javascript'; ga.async = true;
    ga.src = ('https:' == document.location.protocol ? 'https://ssl' : 'http://www') + '.google-analytics.com/ga.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(ga, s);
  })();

</script>
<!-- End Of Analytics Code -->
```

So although you're getting valid JSON from the site in visual text, the web host you are using is tacking on their own javascript in order to push their free services.

As a result these lines in your android fail:

```
// getting JSON Object
// Note that create Drink url accepts POST method
JSONObject json = jsonParser.makeHttpRequest(url_create_Drink,"POST", params);
```

So you have three choices as I see it.

1) Find a new webhost that doesn't do this to your responses. You could try setting up WAMP on your local machine which is not very difficult. It will be more secure for your testing until you learn more about development. For instance, we could SQL Injection attack your DB as it stands.

2) Work with the site and see if there's a way you can have that code not sent

3) Write some code before the android call that filters that portion of the resposnse. You'll need to create a BufferedReader and the like in order to receive the response from the web page.

Comment: I'll give 3 a shot first, would be nice to have it running on areal server :L then I'll try setting it up with WAMP :)